# Check value of one column based on another R

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe

```
Name <- c("Jon", "Jon", "Maria", "Maria", "Tina", "Tina")
Score <- c(23, 23, 32, 32, 26, 78)
df <- data.frame(Name, Score)
```

I would like to see if the Score column is the same or different per name. In theory, I expect the score for each column to be the same per name, but it could be the case that they're different (like with Tina) and I would like to check.

What might be an efficient way to do this? (My dataframe has over 150 000 rows).

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried looping through the df but it was horribly inefficient

Comment: Please show the code, possibly there are easy ways of improvement/using vectorised alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the counts, then you can check if Name is duplicated

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  count(Name, Score)%>%
  add_count(Name, name = "name_n")%>%
  filter(name_n > 1)

#output
  Name Score n name_n
1 Tina    26 1      2
2 Tina    78 1      2
```

Answer (score 0):

would this help ?

```
> df %>% count(Name, Score) %>% filter(n<2)
  Name Score n
1 Tina    26 1
2 Tina    78 1
```